# Why does (Guid?)null ?? default return empty guid

Tags: c#, default, guid, null-coalescing

Output from VS Immediate Window

```
default(Guid?)
=> null
(Guid?)null == default
=> true
(Guid?)null ?? default
=> {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

I expected the last to be `null` and not `Guid.Empty`.
So why is it this way?

Comment: `(Guid?)null` is null, so you get the right part of the `??`. `default(Guid)` is `Guid.Empty`.

Comment: @GSerg but say i have a variable:
`Guid? toCheck = null`
do some fancy stuff, maybe set toCheck or not and later on i check
`var result = toCheck ?? default;`
i would not expect result to be Guid.Empty

Comment: With `var g1 = (Guid?)null; var g2 = g1 ?? default;`, you can observe that the inferred type is `Guid?` for `g1` and `Guid` for `g2`. By changing the latter to `var g2 = g1 ?? default(Guid?);`, you can make `g2` also `Guid?`.

Comment: @GSerg Yes, thank you